# Hue WEB UI not loading in browser

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue

I have a Hue installation on my local machine and the browser loads Hue WEB UI very well in the browser when I give the URL

```
10.20.30.40:8888
```

in my browser.

When i do the same for a remote machine (I have root and hdfs permissions to )with Hue installed, my browser does not load Hue it keeps on processing and waiting (10 - 12 mins).

```
11.22.33.44:8888
```

I can modify the Hue config files on the remote machine. Please tell me what needs to be done to set this right.

Answer (score 2):

If using the package or tarball release, make sure that [http_host](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/desktop/conf.dist/hue.ini#L24) is binding to 0.0.0.0. You could check it after by going on hue_host:8888/dump_config too.

If using Cloudera Manager, go to Services -> Hue -> Configuration -> View and Edit -> Hue Server -> Ports and Addresses and check "Bind Hue Server to Wildcard Address" and restart Hue.

Then Hue should be accessible by external hosts!